# What's the difference between CRP(Critical rendering path) and Blink render pipeline?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, frontend, blink

I am learning browser rendering in [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering) and an article titled [Life of a Pixel](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1boPxbgNrTU0ddsc144rcXayGA_WF53k96imRH8Mp34Y/edit#slide=id.ga884fe665f_64_1800), and there are two concepts: CRP(Critical rendering path) and Blink render pipeline/process.

What's the difference and relationship between them?
Does the browser really build CSSOM when it is rendering?